# How to enable different voices (and languages) for TextToSpeech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to create a simple `TextToSpeech` app that speaks portuguese (`pt_BR`).
The default [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) Android reference does not include `pt_BR`, so I created it:

```
public Locale pt_BR = new Locale("pt", "BR");
...

public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    tts.setLanguage(pt_BR);
}
```

and it works, but with a very "robotic" voice, not smooth at all. Is it possible to download (or even buy) different voices for specific languages? (not an app, but the voice itself, so that I can include the voice as a `TextToSpeech` in my app Project).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. there are few good TTS engines available whihc you can use. They have free versions as well as paid versions which have added features.

**Nuance** Engine is good. It has both TTS and VRS (Voice recognization system). Also you can check **iSpeech**.

But i felt Nuance is better. both have free versions. you can easily integrate and check.